# MySQL: deleting rows with subquery and "not in" is slow

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

products (id {Primary Key}, dcs_no {Indexed} and others) - 1000 rows

product_price_import (dcs_no {Primary Key} and others) - 100 000 rows

I am trying to do this:

```
DELETE 
FROM product_price_import 
WHERE dcs_no NOT IN (SELECT dcs_no FROM products WHERE dcs_no <> '')
```

But, as expected, it takes way too much time
I have come across a solution that should be faster if if it was "IN" instead of "NOT IN"

```
DELETE product_price_import 
FROM products 
JOIN product_price_import ON product_price_import.dcs_no = products.dcs_no;
```

Can anyone tell me how I can optimize the query to delete the rows from product_price_import table that does not have dcs_no values in the products table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `JOIN`, and check for a `NULL` id value in the `products` table:

```
DELETE ppi
FROM product_price_import ppi
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.dcs_no = ppi.dcs_no
WHERE p.dcs_no IS NULL
```

Comment: you mean LEFT OUTER JOIN? Never thought of that

Comment: @TimurGafforov correct, the use of `OUTER` is optional in MySQL

Comment: Using a `LEFT JOIN` and checking for a `NULL` row in the joined table can be a quite efficient way of doing `NOT IN`

Comment: Still taking a lot of time - 89 seconds :-( any other solution to do the delete?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` give?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Had VARCHAR set to dcs_no in products. It works perfectly fine now. Thanks. P.S. Thanks for the hint regarding optionality of "OUTER" - never knew that

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might give performance

```
Delete ppi.* from product_price_import ppi where not exists (select * from products p where p.dcs_no = ppi.dcs_no)


For EX
mysql> select * from empty;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  0 |
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from empty1;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> delete e1.* from empty1 e1 where not exists (select * from empty e where e.id =e1.id);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> select * from empty1;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

also index dcs_no in both tables